# Unity3D: Importing Keyframe Animation (not Bone-based Animation)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender, 3dsmax, fbx

To my knowledge, I can only import Bone-based Animation from 3ds Max or similar. Is there a way to import other types of animation? I'd like to import a construction animation like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWmR9UIz5iA). How can I import these animations in Unity? What is the easiest solution for this type of animation?

Same Question in [UnityAnswers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/387534/importing-keyframe-animation-not-bone-based-animat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual way to do that it is add bones to the all objects that you would like animate.
For example in 3d App you have to create single mesh object which is contain all parts of the engine as sub-meshes and add one bone per sub-mesh (+ setup bone weights), and after it's it could be animated like
standart objects animation (one mesh needed by performance reasons it's important to use only one skinned mesh).

Also you can to try [Mega Fiers](http://www.west-racing.com/mf/?page_id=2) plugin which is provide abilities for vertex and morph animations.